# Why does html jump a gap between content?

Tags: html, css

So I have this problem on my new site ([Click here](http://evoc.cf)).
When you try to scroll down, html suddenly jumps over to the top of the next div(`#Join`). 
Similarly, when you click on 'Join', it suddenly jumps over to the end of the div.
I don't know why this happens but it happened after I inserted a margin-bottom for the header(So unused space between the `header` and `#Join`).

CSS snippets:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 600px;
}

#Join {
    width: 900px;   
    height: 700px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page" class="">
    <div class="background">
        <div class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="3s">
            <header class="static topheader">
                <div style="margin-top: -5px;"class="leftheader toplist">
                    <a id="logo" href="#">Evoc</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" >
                    <ul class="menulist">
                        <li class="menuitem toplist"><a href="#Join">Join</a></li>
                        <li class="menuitem toplist"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="menuitem toplist"><a id="login" href="javascript:void(0)"> Login </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div id="Join">



        </div>
```

Additional plugins I use are:

- Animate.css
- Jquery.js
- Wow.js
- Smoothscroll.js

Question: Why does html jump this gap and how can I prevent it from jumping this gap?

Any help is very much appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Ps. If any further information is necessary, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: because when you scroll down, you are changing the header to fixed positioning. In fixed positioning it goes out of the flow of the DOM. So, the '#Join' goes up and occupies the space what header was occupying when position was not fixed.

Comment: Okay, that sounds logical. Do you have any suggestion for fixing the problem? @Devjit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want that gap between you header and the "#Join" div.
Try this Hack. Put a extra div with some height before "#Join". And Remove the Margin Bottom from header.

```
<div style="height: 600px;"></div>
<div id="Join">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The sudden jump is caused by the multiple break tags you have used after div background.

Instead of using `br` tags, you can specify `margin` or `padding` with respect to the space between or within elements.

[image: Multiple break tags]

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you but it's not caused by that... I added the <br /> so I could test the header(fixed). Also the br tags are after #join. I have removed from my code now.

Comment: I answered this after removing the code. The jump stopped in my browser.

Comment: I have updated the code on my website, please have another look. Your effort is certainly appreciated :)